# Leaflet plugins - how to use two plugins together

Tags: leaflet, plugins

I want to use two leaflet plugins: ExtraMarkers and IconLabel.
How to combine them together? The result should be ExtraMarker with label.

When I create ExtraMarkers:

```
        var icon = L.ExtraMarkers.icon({
            shadowSize: [0,0],
            prefix: 'fa',
            extraClasses: 'fa-fw',
            shape: 'circle',
            icon: 'fa-'+Icon,
            iconColor: IconColor,
            markerColor: MarkerColor
        });
```

or IconLabel

```
        var iconLabel = L.Icon.Label.extend({
            options: {
                iconUrl: 'img/icon.png',
                shadowUrl: null,
                iconSize: new L.Point(24, 24),
                iconAnchor: new L.Point(0, 1),
                labelAnchor: new L.Point(26, 0),
                wrapperAnchor: new L.Point(12, 13),
                labelClassName: 'icon-label'
            }
        });
        var icon = new iconLabel({labelText: title})
```

Comment: Are you receiving an error or unexpected results when trying to combine them? What is the text of the error or what are your results vs. what you are expecting? A little extra info can help us troubleshoot.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to GIS SE!

If you are referring to [Leaflet.iconlabel](https://github.com/jacobtoye/Leaflet.iconlabel) plugin, please note that it is quite old already, and no longer maintained.

As mentioned on its home page, a more simple version is [Leaflet.label](https://github.com/leaflet/Leaflet.label) plugin, for which you just "bind" a label to your marker, whatever its icon (could be your ExtraMarker).

That being said, note that with [Leaflet 1.0.0-rc.2](http://leafletjs.com/2016/07/16/leaflet-1.0-rc2.html), you now have [`L.tooltip`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#tooltip) which provides a similar functionality as Leaflet.label, but styled like Leaflet.iconlabel. In particular, you can also simply bind it to your marker, whatever its icon: [`myMarker.bindTooltip("tooltip text")`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#marker-bindtooltip).

Comment: I'm using Leaflet 1.0.0 rc2. There is  tooltip feature already built in, but it doesn't work with permanent: true. See my code here [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dkolesar/u4mg9nL1/)

Comment: Your marker must be added to map before you can open its tooltip… http://jsfiddle.net/u4mg9nL1/4/